# Can i have aws cli inside a docker file

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, deployment, devops

I have Dockerfile which configures jenkins,installs node and npm, I also want to add aws cli into that docker so that I can use it to deploy the application using pipeline script

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins

USER root

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash - && \
    apt-get install -y nodejs

RUN curl -L https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sh

USER jenkins
```

This is the docker file that I had written, while running the deploy script, a error was shown in jenkins logs below is the error

```
DONE  Build complete. The dist directory is ready to be deployed.
 INFO  Check out deployment instructions at https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html
      
sh: 1: aws: not found
```

Please help how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

You must to add aws cli installation step in your dockerfile:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins

USER root

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash - && \
    apt-get install -y nodejs && \
    curl -L https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sh

USER jenkins

# Create a virtual environment and activate it
RUN python3 -m venv /venv
ENV PATH="/venv/bin:$PATH"

# Upgrade pip within the virtual environment
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

# Install AWS CLI within the virtual environment
RUN pip install awscli
```

Btw, it's not the good practise to use awscli inside jenkins
Also you should combine it into single `RUN` statement to reduce number of layers

Comment: I already tried this approach, got this error while building the docker file


ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get update &&     apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip &&     pip3 install --upgrade pip &&     pip3 install awscli" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

Comment: Put it just before `USER jenkins`